# About normalize in redux real-world example

Tags: redux, react-redux

In the [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/containers/UserPage.js)'s src(UserPage.js):

```
  const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  // We need to lower case the login due to the way GitHub's API behaves.
  // Have a look at ../middleware/api.js for more details.
  const login = ownProps.params.login.toLowerCase()

  const {
    pagination: { starredByUser },
    entities: { users, repos }
  } = state

  const starredPagination = starredByUser[login] || { ids: [] }
  const starredRepos = starredPagination.ids.map(id => repos[id])
  const starredRepoOwners = starredRepos.map(repo => users[repo.owner])

  return {
    login,
    starredRepos,
    starredRepoOwners,
    starredPagination,
    user: users[login]
  }
}
```

I notice that there is many templates like `xxx.ids.map(id => someEntities[id])`,I am not sure why use this pattern to work.IMO,I would use something like `import { map } from 'lodash'; someList && map(someList, item => {...})` in the container component and just pass the entities in the `mapStateToProps`.

So,could someone explains it's purpose?Thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question.  Are you asking about the idea of mapping over IDs to get a list of items, or the use of `Array.map()` instead of `_.map()` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I mean it's not necessary to "mapping over IDs to get a list of items",we can just do something like `import { map } from 'lodash'; someList && map(someList, item => {...})` to work well too.We use `lodash.map` rather than `Array.prototype.map` is because our data is normalized by the `normalizr` library,so the items is a object not an array. @markerikson

Comment: The reason of I am opposed to way(e.g,`xxx.ids.map(id => someEntities[id])`) in the example is that the result data after this step is already exist before this step done.As I say above,we can just pass the entities(from the normalized data by `normalizr` library) in the mapStateToProps to ourcontainer component @markerikson

Comment: And another reason is that it increases the boilerplate code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard suggestion for normalizing data in Redux is to store data items in an object, with IDs as the keys and the items as the values.  However, an object doesn't have an inherent order to it.  (Technically, the order of iteration for object keys *should* be consistent, but it's a bad practice to rely on that as the sole means of ordering.)

Because of that, it's also standard to store an array of just the IDs as well.  A typical example might look like:

```
{
    byId : {
        qwerty : { },
        abcd : { },
        aj42913 : { }    
    },
    items : ["qwerty", "aj42913", "abcd"],
    sorted : ["abcd", "aj42913", "qwerty"],
    selected : ["qwerty", "abcd"]
}
```

In this example, `items` contains *all* item IDs, probably in the order they were insert.  `sorted` contains the IDs in some sort of sorted order, while `selected` contains a subset of the IDs.

This allows the items themselves to only be stored once, while multiple representations of those items can be saved using various arrays of IDs.

From there, you can pull together a list of the actual items by mapping over whatever array of IDs you care about, and retrieving the items by their IDs.

So, ultimately the answer is that relying *just* on the keys of the `byId` object doesn't give you any kind of ordering, and doesn't allow defining subsets of the data.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.In my project,there is some items are very simple (e.g., there is no nest)and their id is just number(e.g., the order of iterate the object must be same as the array),so that's why I post this question.But I am sure I know what you mean.So,thanks again! @markerikson